# Images are not storing in FTP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, ftp

I have tried files upload to server using ftp connection in php and its not working, its connecting but getting Error like "Connected to XXXXXXXXXXX, for user XXXXXXXXXXXXX FTP upload has failed!"
I have tried following code please help by correcting it,..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "XXXX";
$ftp_user_name = "XXXXX";
$ftp_user_pass = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$destination_file = "./imagetest/123/";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: The `$destination_file` variable seems to only be a directory, not a file name.  Per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) the second argument in `ftp_put()` should be a file path.

Comment: `$destination_file = "./imagetest/123/";` its directory only

Comment: I see that it is only a directory.  What I am saying is that it needs to be a file name.  Follow the link in my previous comment to the manual.  It spells it all out what that function expects for arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add filename after path.

Replace below code and try,

```
$destination_file = "./imagetest/123/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$destination_file is not a file it is a directory.

Also you need to change directory to upload file.

Eg.

```
<?php
    ftp_chdir($conn, $destination_directory); 
    ftp_put($conn, $filename , $source_file, FTP_BINARY ); 
?>
```

Comment: You need to specify directory and filename. Not only directory.